# face_recognition classifying similar images as different

Tags: python, face-recognition

I recently saw the YouTube tutorial [Getting Started with Face Recognition in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWoigw6-crg) and tried to follow it myself. Here is the code I tried:

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np

image=face_recognition.load_image_file('IMG_1000.jpg')
unknown=face_recognition.load_image_file('img_0892.jpg')

actual_encoding=  face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
unknown_encoding= face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown)[0]

results=face_recognition.compare_faces([actual_encoding],unknown_encoding)
print(results)
```

The two images referred to in the above code are:
[image: Image 1] and [image: Image 2] which are, as you can see,the same person.

The output, however is:

```
`[False]`
```

Did I do something wrong? If not, what library would you recommend to get accurate predictions on similar pictures?